# python not print response in my laptop, but print in google colab

Tags: python

I'm Trying To Place A Market Order With [www.CoinEx.com](http://www.CoinEx.com)  API. I installed a python package available in:

https://pythonrepo.com/repo/imanmousaei-coinexpy

Coinex.com official Github page:

https://github.com/coinexcom/coinex_exchange_api/wiki

installation:

```
pip install coinexpy
```

the problem is that when I run the following code in  Google colab, I get  reasonable  response:

```
from coinexpy.coinex import Coinex
coinex = Coinex('xxxx', 'xxxx')
coinex.market_sell('BTCUSDT', 2)  # sell 100$ worth of BTC
```

Response:

```
{'code': 602, 'data': {}, 'message': 'Less than minimum requirement'}
```

But when I run the same code on my laptop with python3, it didn't print any response!!

I will be grateful for any idea to solve this problem.

Comment: i think you shound use print(coinex.market_sell('BTCUSDT', 2)) to get the output in terminal

Comment: Mark my answer as accepted if it help you

Comment: Printing return value of last statement is a feature of Google Collab. In terminal or while running the script you have to request prints manually.

Answer (score 1):

I think you shound use `print(coinex.market_sell('BTCUSDT', 2))` to get the output in terminal